# Why is 7-zip much faster than other LZMA implementations in Linux?

Tags: performance, compression, 7z, xz, lzma

Until now, I used to backup my data using `tar` with one of the LZMA compression options (`--lzma`, `--xz` or `--lzip`)

I recently noticed that 7-Zip has been ported to Linux in 2021 (https://www.xda-developers.com/7-zip-linux-official-release/). I'm not talking about the older P7Zip (https://p7zip.sourceforge.net/), that doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, but about the official 7-Zip.

So, I tested it, and was very surprised to discover that it's A LOT faster than all the others Linux LZMA implementations, for the same compression ratio.

Below my tests (Debian 11). Please not that I emptied the RAM cache between every test (`sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`)

I am working on a 163M folder, containing several type of files, PDF, text, open office, and so on...

```
$ du -hs TEST/
163M    TEST/
```

With 7-Zip it's compressed into a 127M file in 15 seconds :

```
$ time tar c -hp TEST/ | 7zz a -si test.tar.7z
real    0m14,565s
(...)

$ ll test.tar.7z
(...) 127M (...) test.tar.7z
```

Whereas with all the other implementations of LZMA, it takes almost 5 times longer (around 1'13"), for the same archive size !

```
$ time tar -chp --lzma -f test.tar.lzma TEST/
real    1m13,159s

$ time tar -chp --xz -f test.tar.xz TEST/
real    1m12,889s

$ time tar -chp --lzip -f test.tar.lz TEST/
real    1m12,525s

$ ll test.tar.{7z,lz*,xz}
(...) 127M (...) test.tar.7z
(...) 127M (...) test.tar.lz
(...) 127M (...) test.tar.lzma
(...) 127M (...) test.tar.xz
```

Just to be sure there's nothing wrong with `tar`, I did the same tests but piped `tar`'s output to `lzma|xz|lzip`, instead of using the `--lzma`, `--xz` and `--lzip` switches. Same results.

So, basically, 7-Zip's Linux version makes all other LZMA implementations look rather bleak. I think 7-Zip doesn't support Linux owners and permissions, but that's irrelevant when compressing a `.tar` file.

So, does anybody know why 7-Zip's Linux version is so much faster than other LZMA implementations ?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my question. Basically, it looks like `7zz` is multi-threaded by default, which isn't the case of `xz` or `lzip`. Throw multi-thread in the equation, and the results get much closer, even if 7-Zip remains a little bit faster :

```
$ time tar c -hp TEST/ | 7zz a -si test.tar.7z
real 0m17,986s

// free memory

$ time tar c -hp TEST/ | xz --threads=0 > test.tar.xz
real 0m22,920s

// free memory

$ sudo apt install plzip

$ time tar -chp --lzip -f test.tar.lz TEST/
real 0m20,134s
```

Interestingly, installing `plzip` (parallel lzip) makes `tar --lzip` using it automatically (probably because `/usr/bin/lzip` becomes a symlink to `/usr/bin/lzip.plzip`, at least in Debian).

[ EDIT ]

Also, note that [since version 5.5.1](https://github.com/tukaani-project/xz/releases) (January 2024), which I did not use, `xz` is multi-threaded by default :

> Multithreaded mode is now the default. This improves compression speed and creates .xz files that can be decompressed multithreaded at the cost of increased memory usage and slightly worse compression ratio.

Answer (score 1):

7zz uses [hand-written assembly](https://github.com/kornelski/7z/tree/main/Asm), p7zip and xz do not.

Besides, XZ's LZMA implementation is very dated. Igor Pavlov has made a ton of changes in 7-zip to speed it up in the last seven years.

Comment: I hope `tar` will add a `--7z` option soon...

Comment: There's no need to wait, you can pipe `tar` output to whatever you need. 7zz can use `stdin` as an input.

Comment: Yes I know, that's what I did in my tests. Works fine. But a `--7z` tar option would be more concise. Plus, a `tar` option is basically a statement that `tar` devs endorse 7-zip as a valid compression tool. Well, that's how I see it...

Comment: tar supports compressors, 7z is an archiver, so there's that.

Comment: I believe `7zz` doesn't save linux ownership and permissions, am I right or has that changed ? If that's still the case, then 7-zip isn't really an archiver in the linux world, and should only be used to compress tar files (or for files for which you don't care about ownership/permissions infos).

Comment: @ChennyStar GNU might mean "GNU's not Unix," so building support for every type of conceivable compressor into GNU `tar` might make sense for that project. However, if you want to do it the Unix way, pipe the archive from `tar` to the compressor of your choice and then redirect the resulting compressed archive to a file.  This is in fact what GNU `tar` does under the hood already, with the compressors that it supports.